# Rspec test - custom route path results in not recognized by rspec "undefined local variable/method"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, rspec

I defined a custom route that works in the app, but not in rspec for some reason.

**/app/config/routes.rb**

```
  get '/signup',   to: 'users#new',             as: :signup
```

The signup page view file has the "signup_path" link, and it works.
/app/views/users/new.html.rb

```
<% provide(:title, 'Sign Up') %>
<h1>Sign Up</h1>
<%= link_to "signup_path", signup_path %>
```

But in rspec, using this test

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe "UserPages -" do

  subject { page }
  let(:base_title) { "Ruby on Rails Tutorial Sample App" }

  describe "Signup Page" do
    before { visit signup_path }

    it { should have_selector('h1', text: 'Sign Up') }
    it { should have_title(full_title('Sign Up')) }
  end

end
```

the result is a failing test, and it says

"signup_path is an undefined local variable or method"

I am using capybara 2.1.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot access named route from your tests unless you add this to `spec_helper.rb`

```
Rspec.configure do |config|
  config.include Rails.application.routes.url_helpers
  ...
end
```